# QRegExp html line

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I had no problems with QRegExp class but now i have one.
My Code

```
QRegExp re("d class=\\.green\\.>([+,0-9]+)<.td><td>[.0-9]+<.td><td>[.0-9]+<..n");
QString str=AliorLinia;

qDebug()<<str;
QStringList list;
int pos=0;

while((pos=re.indexIn(str, pos))!=-1){
    list << re.cap(1);
    pos+=re.matchedLength();
}

qDebug()<<list;
```

console show me

[image]

,line of str is on screen

console should show +0,10 but it show only () why :(?

Comment: HTML is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), so it's seems questionable to use a regular expression to attempt to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get a match because your real *literal* string looks like

```
d class="green">+0.10</td><td>69.7</td><td>69.0</
<NEWLINE>
```

The `\"` and `\n` you see in the debugger are just telling you the *string literal* contains a literal double quote and a newline symbol (a char with decimal code of 10).

Also, your number contains a `.`, not `,` as a decimal separator, so you must add it to the `[+,0-9]` character class.

So, your regex with minimal amendments can look like

```
QRegExp re("d class=.green.>([+.,0-9]+)<.td><td>[.0-9]+<.td><td>[.0-9]+<.\n");
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vy5Ze/2)

Comment: Because it contains a single value inside. What are the 5 values you expect?

Comment: I changed list to QString and now it's ok ,my bad

Answer (score 0):

Because your regex pattern requires the `green` attribute to be surrounded by dots literally - this is what `\\.` stands for in a quoted string.

The regex you really want here is `\\.` (i.e. a backslash literally followed by any character), that's right. But in a C string literal each of these two backslashes should be escaped by an extra slash:

```
QRegExp re("d class=\\\\.green\\\\.>([+,0-9]+)<.td><td>[.0-9]+<.td><td>[.0-9]+<..n");
                    ^ ^       ^ ^
                 add these backslashes
```